# Is there a way to detect when the Firebase Remote Config sends new data to my app?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-remote-config

I have an app where I'm using Firebase Remote Config to fetch things from my server. My app fetches every day, but the content that I have only changes around every month. Is there a way to detect when my Remote Config actually sends new data, versus just fetching what there was before? I have looked into using `UserDefaults` to save the previous data and compare it but I'm not quite sure how that would work. Is there a way, using Firebase, to send a notification to my app that new data has been published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in solution for this. You will have to build something yourself.

You can use Cloud Functions to write a [Remote Config trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/rc-events) that, when your configuration changes, uses [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to notify your app that it should force a reload the config without polling.

[This blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2018/11/using-cloud-functions-to-update-remote) goes over the process in more detail.

Comment: Since that blog post, the same approach as also been added to the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime

Answer (score 1):

There is real time listener functionality provided by google. You can get more information from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=ios#add-real-time-listener).

```
remoteConfig.addOnConfigUpdateListener { configUpdate, error in
   guard let configUpdate, error == nil else {
   print("Error listening for config updates: \(error)")
 }

 print("Updated keys: \(configUpdate.updatedKeys)")

 self.remoteConfig.activate { changed, error in
   guard error == nil else { return self.displayError(error) }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.displayWelcome()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call this method with Swift 5:

```
let expirationDuration: TimeInterval = 3600 // 1 hour
RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration) { [weak self] (status, error) in
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activate()
        // your logic here
    }
```